# Swift SCNAction, rotate to a quaternion

Tags: swift, rotation, quaternions, scnnode, scnaction

I have a planeNode in a SceneKit Scene which I want to control. For this I want to constantly update the Orientation. Due to the Singularities of Euler Angles I am using Quaternions. So far I am directly updating `planeNode.orientation` and it works fine. The only issue is that due to the update rate it slightly jumps between orientations, which does not look very nice. I tried using `SCNActions` but the problem is I can only `rotateTo` and `rotate` by Euler Angles. Is there any way to `rotateTo` Quaternions?

Any help is very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by up using `sims_slerp` and therefore not updating the orientation directly to the new set point orientation but rather to a part of it:

```
let qSlerp = simd_slerp(simd_quatf(quat: self.planeNode.orientation), self.orientationSP!, 0.1)
// UPDATE ORIENTATION TO CLOSEST INTERPOLATION
self.planeNode.orientation = SCNQuaternion(simd_quat: qSlerp)}
```